# How can I grab the columns of many tables efficiently in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to find all columns in some Hive tables that meet a certain criteria.  However, the code I've written to do this is very slow, since Spark isn't a particularly big fan of looping:

```
matches = {}
for table in table_list:
    matching_cols = [c for c in spark.read.table(table).columns if substring in c]
    if matching_cols:
        matches[table] = matching_cols
```

I want something like:

```
matches = {'table1': ['column1', 'column2'], 'table2': ['column2']}
```

How can I more efficiently achieve the same result?

Comment: There is really nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: In theory, no...  but it grows exponentially slower the more tables it reads, even though I'm only scraping the columns.  If I only have a handful of tables, it's totally fine, but it runs for ages when I have 200+ tables in one database to scour.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague just figured it out.  This is the revised solution:

```
matches = {}
for table in table_list:
    matching_cols = spark.sql("describe {}".format(table)) \
                         .where(col('col_name').rlike(substring)) \
                         .collect()

    if matching_cols:
        matches[table] = [c.col_name for c in matching_cols]
```

The key difference here is that Spark seems to be caching partition information in my prior example, hence why it was getting more and more bogged down with each loop.  Accessing the metadata to scrape columns, rather than the table itself, bypasses that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If table fields has comments above code will get into issues on extra info(comment), Also side note HBase link tables will be issue too...

Example:

```
create TABLE deck_test (
COLOR string COMMENT 'COLOR Address',
SUIT string COMMENT '4 type Suits',
PIP string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED by '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

describe deck_test;
color                   string                  COLOR Address
suit                    string                  4 type Suits
pip                     string
```

to handle comments issue small change may help...

```
matches = {}
for table in table_list:
    matching_cols = spark.sql("show columns in {}".format(table)).where(col('result').rlike(substring)).collect()
    if matching_cols:
        matches[table] = [c.col_name for c in matching_cols]
```